# JSON-RPC signrawtransaction returns false when using private keys

Tags: json-rpc, private-key, c#

I've been working with [BitcoinLib](https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib) testing various parameters on the signrawtransaction rpc call.

It's been mostly successful, however there seems to be a persisting problem when using only private keys to sign a transaction. (second optional argument of signrawtransaction call). The server replies `false` and returns the failed hex. I have tested the same transaction on the qt console using the same keys, and it returns `true`.

The wrapper employs a `SignRawTransactionRequest` class matching the four arguments of the rpc call.

```
public SignRawTransactionRequest(String rawTransactionHex)
    {
        RawTransactionHex = rawTransactionHex;
        Inputs = new List<SignRawTransactionInput>();
        PrivateKeys = new List<String>();
        SigHashType = SignRawTransaction.SigHashType.All;
    }
```

It allows for 'inputs' and 'privatekeys' to be null, following the signrawtransaction syntax, while assuming 'sighashtype=all' unless explicitly specified otherwise.

The implementation also includes a `SignRawTransactionInput` class corresponding to the first optional argument of the rpc call. ([{"txid":txid,"vout":n, "scriptPubKey":hex, "redeemScript":hex } ,...])

```
public class SignRawTransactionInput
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "txid", Order = 0)]
    public String TransactionId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "vout", Order = 1)]
    public Int32 Output { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "scriptPubKey", Order = 2)]
    public String ScriptPubKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "redeemScript", Order = 3)]
    public String RedeemScript { get; set; }
}
```

The request if fed to the wrapper method `RpcServer.SignRawTransaction` and returns a `SignRawTransactionResponse` containing the result and the hex as returned by the server.

```
public class SignRawTransactionResponse
    {
        public String Hex { get; set; }
        public Boolean Complete { get; set; }
    }
```

So far, signings using just the hex (no other arguments), inputs, different sighashtypes and various combinations of those have been successful. The server replies TRUE and returns the hex of the signed transaction when called with plain hex

[image]
[image: server reply]

or when called with some arguments

[image]

[image]

However, it returns false when the second optional argument(list of private keys) is used. It has been tested with one, all, and various combinations of the available private keys of the wallet.

[image] [image]

I suspect it might be a JSON error and that the wrapper is not constructing that part of the JSON properly, however that usually leads to a parsing error and not the `false` reply I get here.

The same combinations return `true` when signrawtransaction is called from the console.

[image]

Any ideas on what might be wrong with the private keys argument?

Comment: Did you every manage to figure this out? I'm doing battle with the same RPC method, trying to sign a raw transaction with by providing the necessary private keys rather than unlocking the wallet. Unfortunately it's proving problematic...

Comment: @Tony you have to provide the right keys to sign each unspent input used. Raw transactions have been tested extensively for this library and they work as expected but if you have some specific issue feel free to report it at: https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not a case of BitcoinLib malfunctioning in any way. It was simply a case of using wrong privkeys to sign the unspent outputs.