# BitcoinLib SignRawTransaction JSON-RPC returns false when using private key

Tags: signrawtransaction

This is a repost of ([JSON-RPC signrawtransaction returns false when using private keys](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/20298/json-rpc-signrawtransaction-returns-false-when-using-private-keys)) but I could not comment because of my reputation (new user).

I've been using BitcoinLib via Litecoin Testnet for a week now and I got stuck with SignRawTransaction. It returns false but when I use the RPC call via litecoin-cli

```
litecoin-cli.exe signrawtransaction 020000000152cf5e76f1ac0fd42e97ec60db30406b019621da497601b430e7adf5642e1fa20000000000ffffffff02e09c4100000000001976a914fbb4b6ef02914490e99f899cb8538b03105331df88acc095a905000000001976a91471efff92af2740dd4fe088fc3de98ceebaa4c13488ac00000000 "[]" "[\"cQ3HSi45qrfGGZjYAci22gATWfhb1QhWR8JGBHBbzbPsD8Uuu2n2\"]"
```

the result is OK.

This is how I use the SignRawTransaction (Sample):

```
SignRawTransactionRequest signRawRequest = new SignRawTransactionRequest("020000000152cf5e76f1ac0fd42e97ec60db30406b019621da497601b430e7adf5642e1fa20000000000ffffffff02e09c4100000000001976a914fbb4b6ef02914490e99f899cb8538b03105331df88acc095a905000000001976a91471efff92af2740dd4fe088fc3de98ceebaa4c13488ac00000000");
signRawRequest.AddKey("cQ3HSi45qrfGGZjYAci22gATWfhb1QhWR8JGBHBbzbPsD8Uuu2n2");

SignRawTransactionResponse signRawResponse = coinService.SignRawTransaction(signRawRequest);
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Which version of BitcoinLib are you using?

Comment: BitcoinLib Version 1.7.1

Comment: How do you create the `coinService` instance? Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Since I'm using the testnet this is how I created the instance.
ICoinService coinService = new LitecoinService(true);

Comment: It could be a bug in the `LitecoinService`. I assume it works fine with the other implementations(?)

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my local. Can you provide a sample? It could be a .ZIP file, a GitHub repo, a Gist or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but there were missing inputs when I created my Raw transaction. This error has nothing to do with BitcoinLib.